# Django: use AdminLTE as template in views

Tags: django, django-templates

I have to start a project in Django which will be used internally in our company so no need to use a custom layout, adminLTE2 template or similar should be just fine. The project is used to manage internal stuff, this project could get bigger as it evolves and we need to add new features.

My doubt is that I don't know where and how to use it, if in the Django admin part or integrate and use it as app template. From what I understand, working with django admin it's not fully customizable as working with app template, this makes me a little bit confused.

In short: should I use the Django admin or app template? how can I integrate AdminLTE or similar as django app template?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

> should I use the Django admin or app template?

Depend of your project requirements. If you need some basic stuff with your admin will be enought but if you need more complex things you will need to do it like an "app template" like you said.

> how can I integrate AdminLTE or similar as django app template?

I think you need something like this https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-adminlte2/latest/django-adminlte2.pdf. The file explain very well how to integrate the django-adminlte2 app in your project.

Answer (score 0):

To use adminlte in your django app , follow below steps

1. Install adminlte in your virtual environment of your project.
   pip install django-adminlte2
2. Add adminlte app into settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS before your app name

   'django_adminlte_theme',

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with new version of AdminLTE, as of now the version is 3.0 with bootstrap 4, and fontawesome 5.

```
pip install django-adminlte3
```

you should add *adminlte3* and *adminlte3_theme* to installed apps.

[pypi address](https://pypi.org/project/django-adminlte3/)